# Help impress interviewer with javascript and jQuery skills

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

One of the interviewers asked to impress him with the JavaScript and CSS skills. He provided a link to two websites and asked to write a JavaScript application (page or pages) that takes content from one or both of these websites and demonstrates my command of jQuery and CSS. It doesn’t have to be useful to end-users, but it should be interesting to programmers.

What interesting things should I write? What would impress you in the candidate?

P.S.
The sites have real-estate information.

So, what would be the best way to read information from a given URL and extract some of it using jQuery?

Comment: If he really said "impress me with js and css skills" then you probably don't want to be working with/for him.

Comment: @Cherouvim: I second that.  You want a company that values ambition and hard work.  Rather than, 'What do you know?'.

Comment: Well, to tell you the truth, this is not for me, this is for a friend of mine, he asked to help. He says the job is close to his home and he really needs it. So, please help with what could be done.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable at all for an employer to ask for a demonstration of applicable skills.

Comment: So you want someone to show your friend a nifty trick that he couldn't come up with on his own?  Sounds like the potential employer would sniff out a rat eventually.

Comment: It surprises me this is voted down, I understand that people wouldn't want to work for a company that interviewed like this, but the OP is asking a legitimate question about what JS, JQ, and CSS skills are considered 'impressive' to an employer

Comment: Ambition and hard work are fine, but the employer has a right to know if they will have to spend months training you on JS and CSS.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote because this question is too broad and provides too little detail. Seeing the two actual web sites would help, for example

Comment: to Stephen - no, I want ideas, what do you want to see from the potential employee. And I am not an expert in jQuery, so a bit of help here would be nice. The guy said to "use imagination"

Comment: to Pekka - I sent him an email asking what is there on the sites.

Comment: Could you post the two sites that you can pull data from?

Answer (score 1):

That interview question is so subjective. What impresses one person might be basic to another. Why not ask a more meaningful question that demonstrates whether or not the candidate actually knows the language.

With all that said and if you really want to work for this company, I would study up on the basics of both js and jquery and really learn how to optimize basic functions. If you had to impress me then you should try to optimize a block of code as best you can without making the code unreadable. There's nothing better than clean, fast and readable code.

Comment: they ask for some actual code that reads from 2 pages and creates a new one with data from the other two.

Comment: @Romario - so basically they want to see a "Mashup". e.g. you take the data for all Starbucks[TM] locations, & all the neighborhood parks and overlay that on top of a Google Map.

Comment: May be that, they didn't tell what they want, most likely they just want to see that you can write jQuery + some css. But mashup sounds like a good idea.